# NumPy matrix multiplication why is a 2x2 multiplied by a 2x1 matrix outputting a 2x2?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

The following code outputs a 2x2 matrix. Shouldn't it output a 2x1 matrix?

```
# dimension check
A = np.array([[-0.0106383,  -0.02553191],
 [-0.02553191, -0.0662766 ]])
B = np.array([114.8, -48. ])
A*B.T
```

outputs:

```
array([[-1.22127684,  1.22553168],
       [-2.93106327,  3.1812768 ]])
```

When I input it on a matrix calculator I obtain a 2x1 matrix. How can I understand this?

Comment: did you mean https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html ? (i.e. `A.dot(B.T)`)

Comment: OK -- that solves it @hiroprotagonist  I can also use ```A @ B.T```  thanks so much

Comment: `B` is **not** 2 by 1.  Check its shape..  `B.T` has the same shape (2,).  And read what `np.dot` says about 1d arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` operator, when used with `np.array`, multiplies that elements of the arrays. What you want instead is the `np.dot` operator. That will calculate the dot product of you matrices.

Using your example numbers, here is what you would want:

```py
A = np.array([[-0.0106383,  -0.02553191],
 [-0.02553191, -0.0662766 ]])
B = np.array([[114.8], [-48. ]]) # I changed this to be shape (2,1)

multiplied = np.dot(A, B)
```